# how to find smallest number greater than an integer

Tags: c++, search, data-structures, maps, std

here i don't have the code but i m am looking to use a map which stores integer values. My sole purpose is to find the smallest integer that is greater than a specific integer.

**Can anyone help me out with the code ?**

what will be the average and worst time complexity for this function ? will it be O(logn) where n are the no. of key value pairs stored in the map.

Lastly is there any other data structure to do this task in quicker way, if we only need to store integer values, no requirement of key - value pairs ?

Comment: You probably want `std::set<int>` instead of some type of `std::map`

Comment: I suggest using a red and black search binary tree, it's pretty quick and it would sort things in a good way for your purpose

Comment: Why store the values?  You are looking for the smallest value, which can be a *running* variable or value.

Comment: What's the input to this problem? A string of numbers (such as from user input, a file stream, etc.)? Or is the input a map that's already filled?

Comment: Hi interesting question, perhaps [`set::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/upper_bound/) can help

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <map>

std::map<..., int> m;
int number = ..., smallest;
bool found = false;

for (auto &item : m)
{
    if (item.second > number)
    {
        if ((!found) || (item.second < smallest))
            smallest = item.second;
        found = true;
    }
}

if (found)
{
    // use smallest as needed...
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

std::map<..., int> m;
int number = ..., smallest;
bool found = false;

for (auto &item : m)
{
    if (item.second > number)
    {
        smallest = std::min(item.second, found ? smallest : item.second);
        found = true;
    }
}

if (found)
{
    // use smallest as needed...
}
```

Alternatively, in C++17 and later...

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <optional>
#include <algorithm>

std::map<..., int> m;
int number = ...,
std::optional<int> smallest;

for (auto &item : m)
{
    if (item.second > number)
        smallest = std::min(item.second, smallest.value_or(item.second));
)

if (smallest.has_value())
{
    // use smallest as needed...
}
```